# Graph in popup on hover with R Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to get a plot to appear in a popup when the user `hovers` for lets say 500 milliseconds over a checkbox in my app. This in order to allow the user to inspect the data in the data column that the `checkbox` represents to include or include in his or her analysis

I have been trying with bsModals, popify and tipify, but I first of all I end up with a text string in the popup, or nothing at all, and only on click events so far. Anyone suggestions how to do this?

Would be much appreciated to learn how to do this!

A piece of dummy code to work on:

```
library(shiny)

shinyApp(


  ui = fluidPage(
    sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
        sliderInput("bins",
                    "Number of bins:",
                    min = 1,
                    max = 50,
                    value = 30),
        bsTooltip("bins", "The wait times will be broken into this many equally spaced bins",
                  "right", options = list(container = "body"))
      ),
      mainPanel(
        checkboxInput(inputId = "Check", "Graph here in popup when I hover here?"))
    )


  ),
  server =  function(input, output, session) {
    output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
      # generate bins based on input$bins from ui.R
      x    <- faithful[, 2]
      bins <- seq(min(x), max(x), length.out = input$bins + 1)

      # draw the histogram with the specified number of bins
      hist(x, breaks = bins, col = 'darkgray', border = 'white')
    })
    observeEvent(input$Check, { 
      print("1")
      showModal(div(id="modalAutoSaveMenu", modalDialog(
        inputId = "distPlot",
        title = HTML('<span style="color:#339fff; font-size: 20px; font-weight:bold; font-family:sans-serif ">Current data column<span>
                     <button type = "button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" ">
                     <span style="color:#339fff; ">x <span>
                     </button> '),
        br(),
        plotOutput("distPlot"),
        br(),
        easyClose = TRUE,
        footer = NULL )))
    })
  }
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've used `shinyjs` to trigger an action based on `hover` but the lapsing time is something i couldn't crack yet.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

shinyApp(


  ui = fluidPage(
    useShinyjs(),
    sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
        sliderInput("bins",
                    "Number of bins:",
                    min = 1,
                    max = 50,
                    value = 30),
        bsTooltip("bins", "The wait times will be broken into this many equally spaced bins",
                  "right", options = list(container = "body"))
      ),
      mainPanel(
        checkboxInput(inputId = "Check", "Graph here in popup when I hover here?"))
    )


  ),
  server =  function(input, output, session) {
    output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
      # generate bins based on input$bins from ui.R
      x    <- faithful[, 2]
      bins <- seq(min(x), max(x), length.out = input$bins + 1)

      # draw the histogram with the specified number of bins
      hist(x, breaks = bins, col = 'darkgray', border = 'white')
    })
    observeEvent(input$Check, { 
      print("1")
      showModal(div(id="modalAutoSaveMenu", modalDialog(
        inputId = "distPlot",
        title = HTML('<span style="color:#339fff; font-size: 20px; font-weight:bold; font-family:sans-serif ">Current data column<span>
                     <button type = "button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" ">
                     <span style="color:#339fff; ">x <span>
                     </button> '),
        br(),
        plotOutput("distPlot"),
        br(),
        easyClose = TRUE,
        footer = NULL )))
    })

    onevent('mouseover','Check',{


delay(1000, 
showModal(div(id="modalAutoSaveMenu", modalDialog(
          inputId = "distPlot",
          title = HTML('<span style="color:#339fff; font-size: 20px; font-weight:bold; font-family:sans-serif ">Current data column<span>
                       <button type = "button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" ">
                       <span style="color:#339fff; ">x <span>
                       </button> '),
          br(),
          plotOutput("distPlot"),
          br(),
          easyClose = TRUE,
          footer = NULL )))) }, T)
      }
    )
```

Comment: nice! the delay is easy. Wrap the whole modal dialog inside a:  delay(1000, ....modal.... )

Comment: I was wrong, it actually doesn't work the way I intended. It only delays the display of the popup by a second, not see if the mouse hovers for one second on the position

Comment: What package is `bsTooltip` part of?